# Unity Gradle Build Failed how to solve?

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
Having this issue for few days, tried out many youtube video related but no helps.

Unity Version 2021.3.11f1
```

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':launcher'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':launcher:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :launcher
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom'.
               > dl.google.com
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom'.
               > jcenter.bintray.com

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\gradle-6.1.1-all\gradle-6.1.1\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleDebug"

Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 851 seconds (851033 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

Anyone could help me on this? Appreciate that TT
I followed many tutorial videos from YouTube (Youtuber: Code Prof, SDP STUDIOS, Mr. Error Assistant) but none of the video helped me...

Comment: Do you have Android studio with an installation of the API version level you're trying to build?

Comment: Yes, those Youtube videos are also teaching this step.